# how make difference between files on the basis of file size in perl

Tags: perl

I am writing a script where i have 3 level dir like below:

```
LOG
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
└── sdlog
    ├── 1log
    │   ├── a.txt
    │   └── b.txt
    └── 2log
        ├── a.txt
        └── b.txt
```

Name of the file are same but the size will always diff. I have to compare the which is in `LOG` dir and `1log` dir on the basis of size take those files. Files which are there in the `2log` we are not going to do any thing.

I have written the script which are printing the files name but not able to above task:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Basename;
my $new_file_name;
my $start_directory = "C:\\logs";


find({ wanted => \&renamefile }, $start_directory);
sub renamefile 
{
  if ( -f and /\.txt$/ )
   {
     my $file = $_;
     open (my $rd_fh, "<", $file);
     LINE: while (<$rd_fh>) 
     {
      if (/<(\d)>/i)
      {
       close $rd_fh;
       print"$file\n";
       #print" Kernal-> $file\n";
       last LINE;
       }
    if (/I\/am_create_activity/i)
    {
     close $rd_fh;
     print"$file\n";
       #print" EVENT-> $file\n";
     last LINE;
     }
  } 
}
}
```

Comment: Use `-s` to get the size of a file. Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: my intention is to compare Dir->LOG ->a.txt,b.txt to subdir->1log->a.txt,b.txt . file which is haveing larg size i want that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-s` to get the file size. Since you are not recursively searching the subdirectories, you do not need `File::Find`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename;

my $path1 = 'LOG';
my $path2 = 'LOG/sdlog/1log';

for my $file (glob "$path1/*.txt") {
    my $name = basename($file);

    if (-f "$path2/$name") {

        if (-s $file > -s "$path2/$name") {
            print $file, "\n";

        } else {
            print "$path2/$name\n";
        }

    } else {
        warn "File $path2/$name not found.\n";
    }
}
```